# Enforce a member destruction order compile-time in C++

Tags: c++, destructor

I have a C++ class `A` like this:

```cpp
// third-party classes / methods, unable to change
class C {};
class B {
public:
    C* getC();
};
B* legacyAPIToGetB(const char*);

// the target class
class A {
public:
    A() {
        // not using initialization lists
        // because something have to be calculated prior B construction
        b = std::unique_ptr<B>(legacyAPIToGetB("calculated value"));
        // throw an exception (don't construct A) if B cannot be constructed
        if (!b) throw std::exception{"Cannot get B"};

        c = std::unique_ptr<C>(b->getC());
        if (!c) throw std::exception{"Cannot get C"};
    }

    std::unique_ptr<B> b = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<C> c = nullptr;
};
```

Say `b` is a dynamic library handle, and `c` is an object created with that library.
In this case, destructor of `b` is called after `c`, which is fine.

However if someone later reorganizes the code, they could accidentally swap the declaration of `b` and `c`.
Thus the destruction order is reversed, leading to possibly hard-to-diagnose runtime crash.

I want to make sure if someone accidentally makes that change, the code should fail to compile (possibly with a custom error message). Is this possible?

(Or maybe this design is flawed from the beginning?)

---

I tried to use `static_assert` to ensure a member order:

```cpp
static_assert(
    reinterpret_cast<void*>(&reinterpret_cast<A*>(nullptr)->b)
    < reinterpret_cast<void*>(&reinterpret_cast<A*>(nullptr)->c),
    "destruction of b should be after c");
```

However, this seems invalid C++ code which only works in MSVC.

**Update**: One may use the [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) macro to check the layout of members, see [IlCapitano's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76660357/16177472) for detail.
While "if type is not a standard layout type (since C++11), the result of offsetof is undefined (until C++17) / use of the offsetof macro is conditionally-supported (since C++17)", it seems major compilers supported it at least in this situation.

<strike>(I'm not even sure whether asserting the memory layout guarantees the destruction order!)</strike>
**Update**: Unfortunately, it's not guaranteed that the members declared later will have higher addresses, until C++23.

> (until C++23): Members separated by an access specifier (until C++11) / with different access control (since C++11) are allocated in unspecified order (the compiler may group them together). [source](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Layout)

---

As noted in the comment, it's possible to use a custom destructor to `reset` the pointers in the correct order:

```cpp
A::~A() {
    // destruction of b should be after c
    c.reset();
    b.reset();
}
```

However [if a constructor throws an exception, the object’s destructor is not run](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#selfcleaning-members).
As noted above, I'm throwing an exception from `A::A()` if something goes wrong. This is also a reason why I use `unique_ptr`s.

It's possible to use some tricks (e.g. keep the other values local, and `std::swap` them into the class in one go) to achieve exception safety, however, this is added complexity.

Comment: How about creating a destructor which [`release`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/release) the objects in the correct order? Then the order of destruction is irrelevant. Remember to add documentation and comments to say why this is needed.

Comment: You could define the destructor and manually release the unique pointers yourself, with a comment.

Comment: @some-programmer-dude @trojanfoe [If a constructor throws an exception, the object’s destructor is not run.](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/exceptions#selfcleaning-members) This is a practical situation in my class, which is why I use `unique_ptr` for automatic `delete`-ing. Sure we can use other tricks to achieve exception safety, but that's added complexity.

Comment: That should have been a very important part of the question itself. This is why we so often ask posters to include a proper [mre]. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: @some-programmer-dude It's easy to get overcomplicated this way. Never mind, additional context added.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<B> b = nullptr;` - this is a bit weird. The default ctor does the same thing.

Comment: For your `static_assert`, you might do it with [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof).

Comment: *"// not using initialization lists"*. You might, even with your constraints; immediate called lambda (or regular function) might do the job.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a case where the ownership is artificially simplified. Since `c` needs `b` alive, it would make sense for `c` to own a `shared_ptr<B>`. This ownership would be shared with `class A`.

Swapping `A::b` and `A::c` would cause `A::c` to be reset early, but the `C` library remains loaded because `b` still has a pointer.

Comment: This is the ideal solution if I'm able to modify `B` and `C`. However, in this situation, these classes are not under our control (i.e. from a third-party). Question updated for clarification.

Comment: @AlexGuo1998: You can always wrap `B` and/or `C`. In particular, here it should be easy to combine `C` and `std::shared_ptr<B>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`offsetof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/offsetof) macro to get the offsets of the members as constant expressions. You will need to put the `static_assert` either outside of the class (if the members are public), or inside of a member function (if the members are private) for it to work.

```
class A {
    std::unique_ptr<B> b = nullptr;
    std::unique_ptr<C> c = nullptr;
    
    static void ensure_order() {
        static_assert(offsetof(A, b) < offsetof(A, c), "'b' needs to be declared before 'c'");
    }
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn’t work because `offsetof` only works on standard layout types, and having a `std::unique_ptr` member automatically makes the type non-standard layout.

Comment: @KonradRudolph `std::unique_ptr` can be (and usually is because `default_delete` would have no members) a standard layout type, meaning that `A` would be standard layout. Even so, `offsetof` is "conditionally supported" on non-standard layout types, and most compilers allow it to be used for direct members of all types

Comment: @Artyer [The compiler seems to disagree](https://godbolt.org/z/PM7nn4GoK). I have to admit that I am a bit rusty, not having used C++ in over a year, but I also remember the *informal* requirement that `offsetof` only works on PODs which can’t have a custom destructor, and `std::unique_ptr<T, std::default_delete<T>>` definitely has that.

Comment: I think the real question is "Is the compiler required to put `b` at a lower memory address than `c`, if `b` is defined earlier?" However this is not guaranteed before C++23. [Members separated by an access specifier (until C++11) / with different access control (since C++11) are allocated in unspecified order (the compiler may group them together)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Layout). Meanwhile, checking (MSVC, clang, GCC) in C++14 mode shows they do not group members. [result](https://godbolt.org/z/cbcz9c3E4)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually enforce that the destructor is run when a constructor throws an expression. The trick is to use a delegating constructor:

```
class A {
private:
    explicit A(nullptr_t) {}    // does the "default" construction
public:
    A() :
        A(nullptr)     // delegate to a "default" constructor
    {
        b = std::unique_ptr<B>(legacyAPIToGetB("calculated value"));
        // throw an exception if B cannot be constructed
        if (!b) throw std::exception{"Cannot get B"};
        // if the exception is thrown, the destructor will run
        // because the A object is already fully constructed

        c = std::unique_ptr<C>(b->getC());
        if (!c) throw std::exception{"Cannot get C"};
    }
    A::~A() {
        // destruction of b should be after c
        c.reset();
        b.reset();
    }


    std::unique_ptr<B> b;
    std::unique_ptr<C> c;
};
```

In the example, I used a constructor with an argument (`A(nullptr_t)`) to which construction is delegated. But if in your code the "actual" constructor takes arguments, you can delegate to the default constructor instead.